# Wait for the refreshing process to finish, before going into next line in code

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to use VBScript to open an external application and refresh it using Sendkeys. How can I pause code at sendkeys"R" line(Using to refresh data), and go to the next line after the refresh operation is completed?.

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
objShell.Run("""C:\Users\PC\Documents\CAP.pbix""")
do
WScript.Sleep 15000
objShell.AppActivate"CAP"
objShell.SendKeys"%{H}"
WScript.Sleep 1500
objShell.SendKeys"R"
WScript.Sleep 1500
objShell.SendKeys"%{H}"
WScript.Sleep 1500
objShell.SendKeys"PU" 
WScript.Sleep 1500
objShell.SendKeys"{Enter}"
WScript.Sleep 1500
objShell.SendKeys"{Esc}"
WScript.Sleep 2500
loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only `sleep` and hope that it is long enough. There's no other way to know if the application has completed the refresh.